Why is the shaded area of my graph shading the whole thing rather than just the AM PM areas?
I am trying to shade the background of my ggplot so that the AM is a lighter shade and the PM is darker.
Here is my data:
date       time dosage ww Group   id  no3 po4 ToD hour_shade
1 2024-09-30 11:20:00 11H 20M 0S   full  5     A A5-1  8.9 3.8  AM     gray90
2 2024-09-30 11:20:00 11H 20M 0S   full  5     A A5-2 12.8 4.0  AM     gray90
3 2024-09-30 11:20:00 11H 20M 0S   full  5     A A5-3 10.4 3.8  AM     gray90
4 2024-09-30 11:20:00 11H 20M 0S   half  5     B B5-1  5.2 2.0  AM     gray90
5 2024-09-30 11:20:00 11H 20M 0S   half  5     B B5-2  5.2 1.9  AM     gray90
6 2024-09-30 11:20:00 11H 20M 0S   half  5     B B5-3  5.2 1.8  AM     gray90

Here is the code for my graph:
nitratePlot = lt2 %>% filter(!is.na(ToD)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = date, y = no3) +
  geom_point(shape = "circle", size = 1.5) +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "[NO3]") +
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(vars(dosage)) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 day",
    expand = c(0.05, 0.05)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.POSIXct("2024-9-29 11:20:00"), xmax = as.POSIXct("2024-10-11 0:0:00"), ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
                fill = hour_shade),
            alpha = 0.1) +
    geom_point()+
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))

For some reason it just shades the whole middle section Gray60:
(https://i.sstatic.net/v83u61Vo.png).
I think it might have to do something with my x axis being date rather than time but idk if there is a way around that.
Thanks!

By using xmin = as.POSIXct("2024-9-29 11:20:00"), xmax = as.POSIXct("2024-10-11 0:0:00"), you make a single rectangle that covers that entire time window. This rectangle is then plotted n times, because you fill has n elements, which is why your alpha probably has no effect. You need to set xmin and xmax to data columns for the beginning and end time of each rectangle.
